# How do I set a style for the contents of an element or div?

Tags: html, css, descendant

I know you can use `ELEMENT * {...}` to set a style for each individual item in ELEMENT, but I want to style the contents as a whole. I also know that you can use `ELEMENT #DIVID {...}` however I don't want to include another DIV in my code.

If you you are thinking why don't I just style the entire `ELEMENT {}`, it is because when I use padding, I do not want my `ELEMENT` to change size based on the padding.

This is what I have at the moment;

CSS Code:

```
article {
  background: #fff;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0dc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #e0e0dc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #e0e0dc;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #e0e0dc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

article #content {
  padding: 25px;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<article>
  <div id="content">
    <h2>Test Title</h2>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

I do not want to have the content DIV.

Comment: Can you post a block of HTML that shows everything? It's far easier to get a feel for what you're trying to do then. CSS would also be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for each type of ELEMENT *within* ELEMENT:

```
ELEMENT DIV, ELEMENT SPAN, ...  {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that have the same effect as ELEMENT * {...}? I also don't want the padding on each individual sub-element, I want the padding around all the sub elements without using a DIV.

Comment: hmm, i must have misunderstood what you meant by that. if that's how you're using it then it shouldn't add any padding to the main ELEMENT. why would you not just use `ELEMENT * {...}`?

Comment: I edited my above comment to answer this but I will repeat it. I don't want the padding on each individual element, I want the padding around the group of elements. However, if I place the padding in ELEMENT {...}, the ELEMENT increases in size according to the amount of padding.

Comment: thanks @MetaDark, I actually did read that, I'm asking why don't you use `ELEMENT * {...}` (with an asterisk). That is identical to my answer and shouldn't add any padding to the main ELEMENT.

Comment: Because if I have something like <p>Something</p><p>Test</p>, there will be a space two times the size of the padding between the paragraphs.